# EEA Citizen planning move to UK -Can my Non-EEA partner move with me along with our EEA citizen child?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, uk-visa

Dual citizen of Finland and Zambia currently residing in Zambia, planning to move to UK. I would like my partner, a Zambian citizen, along with our child, who is also dual citizen of Finland and Zambia, to accompany. Should my partner apply for EEA family permit or would a standard visitor visa be better in this case?

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason to apply for a visitor visa, and at least one good reason not to: a visitor's visa does not authorize the holder to move to the UK.

There are many good reasons to apply for the EEA family permit, however, including the fact that it is free of charge and the fact that it should be issued quickly.

Apply for the EEA family permit.